# FTP download converts CrLf to Lf

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm downloading textfiles from a FTP-Server using this code (directories contains a list of files/directories from the FTP server):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= directories.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            string trnsfrpth = f.getConfig("TempPath") + @"/" + directories[i].ToString();

            if (directories[i].Contains(".") && !(directories[i].ToString().Equals(".") || directories[i].ToString().Equals("..")))
            {
                FtpWebRequest fileFtpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(f.getConfig("FTP") + @"/" + directories[i].ToString());
                fileFtpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                fileFtpRequest.Credentials = credentials;
                fileFtpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

                Stream fileResponse = fileFtpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(trnsfrpth, FileMode.Create);

                while (true)
                {
                    bytesRead = fileResponse.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                        break;

                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                fileStream.Close();

            }
```

The files I get all have LF as line break character. I'm not 100% sure the files have a CR LF line break to begin with. But if I download them via FileZilla, they use CR LF. I need the CR LF version of the files. I wanted to ask if I'm doing something wrong here or if this code is ok and FileZilla automatically converts the files when downloading and I have to replace LF manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have  `fileFtpRequest.UseBinary = true;` and you are using a binary FileStream on the download side.

So it's not the FTP client that converts anything, you want the conversion that FilZilla apparently does but that you're not getting.

You could try with `UseBinary=false` but the docs are vague about the effect.

A StreamReader accepts '\n', so you could replace your `while(true)` part with

```
using (Stream fileResponse = fileFtpRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileResponse))
{
   string line;
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       something.WriteLine(line);  // here you get the .NET line ending
   }
}
```

Comment: `UseBinary = false;` did it. Everyone I asked told me I have to set it to true and that I'd have to look somewhere else -.- Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

The "Binary" transfer mode of FTP copies files exactly, byte for byte. Simple and straightforward.

When bringing text files between different operating systems, though, this might not be what you want -- different operating systems use different codes to represent line breaks. The "ASCII" mode exists for this purpose: it automatically translates all line endings from the source system's format to the destination's.
[LINK](https://serverfault.com/questions/110699/ascii-vs-binary-vs-auto)